# How to turn a Google Analytics event into a trackable conversion in Adwords

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads-api

I am managing an account in Adwords. The developer and UX have decided to track events rather than conversions in Google Analytics. Since for events, there is no unique URL for placing a tracking code as is the typical method in Adwords, we need a way to convert events in a trackable goal in Adwords.

Can someone walk me through the process for doing this? I have contacted Google support for some help on this issue, but this is a relatively new feature so they were not much help this time around.

I essentially need to track a click. I know how to do this, but as this is a large client, changing code on their site is a big pain. I'd rather just turn an event into a conversion via the Analytics interface.

Comment: Create an event based goal in GA and then follow https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/2375435. This is really simple and straightforward.

Comment: http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/how-to-use-events-goals-google-analytics

Comment: The support articles on this suck. That's why I was asking for a good walkthrough on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below article actually helped me understand what the heck to do.

[How to use events as goals in Analytics](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2011/03/how-to-use-events-goals-google-analytics)

The official documentation on this is terrible. It's a somewhat complex task if you've never done it before.

So just do the above, then import as normal from your analytics account.